# Connect QTP and ALM in Citrix

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How we can connect QTP 11 to ALM in Citrix?
I need to run scripts from QTP that has been stored in ALM.
Also i have to store the screen shots in ALM.
Please suggest me some framework idea on this.

Comment: Is your QTP licence citrix supported one?

Comment: @PankajJaju yes. we are working on citrix environment.

Comment: Why can´t you connect QTP with ALM the traditional way , even under Citrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the screenshot question: **To save the screenshots in the run result in ALM, you will need to store the run result in ALM.
To do so, the test must be part of an ALM test set.**

If you start the run from QTP, that test set must be selected as the target for the run result of the test run.

If you start the run from ALM´s test execution scheduler (i.e. directly from the test set in the test lab), this will be automatically the case.

To see the screenshots, just view a such a run result from ALM (or open it manually from run result viewer).

I imply that you use QTP´s screenshotting features. If you create screenshots differently, just make sure they are stored in a directory of the run result, and they will be automatically be part of the run result. To view them, you´d open the run result, and then look at the local run result copy (in temp, or whereever) to find your custom screenshot files.